# How to set sum contrasts for unbalanced factors

Tags: categorical-data, continuous-data, unbalanced-classes, contrasts, treatment-effect

Let's say that I have a model where the response time depends on accuracy (0/1, coded either as categorical or numerical) and another categorical variable (pres: idem/diff), both interacting with the group the subject is nested within (dummy coded, 3 groups NC, HC, NI, ref=NC).

In sum, there is a continuous dependent variable (rt) and three factors as predictors: \n

- pres (takes either the value "idem" or 'diff')
- acc (either 1 or 0)
- group (either HC, NC or NI, the reference level being NC)

The model is:

```
l<-lmer(rt~acc * group + pres * group + other_covariates + (1|suj)); summary(l)

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error      df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       1031.02      63.58   69.00  16.216  < 2e-16 ***
acc                -91.40      22.66 6501.00  -4.032 5.58e-05 ***
groupHC            144.10      85.88   70.00   1.678 0.097831 .  
groupNI            164.40      91.45   70.00   1.798 0.076530 .  
presidem            43.16      14.58 6495.00   2.961 0.003079 ** 
acc:groupHC        -57.68      31.17 6500.00  -1.850 0.064316 .  
acc:groupNI       -114.25      33.27 6499.00  -3.434 0.000599 ***
groupHC:presidem   -27.60      19.82 6495.00  -1.393 0.163809    
groupNI:presidem   -38.39      20.90 6495.00  -1.837 0.066299 .  
........
........
```

If i'm not mistaken, in this case, the intercept is the mean rt for group NC where all other predictors are set to their reference value: So that would be the mean for group NC when acc=0 and pres=diff. Similarly, the coefficient "groupHC" is the augmentation of rt in group HC compared to NC, still when acc=0 and pres=diff.
(I didn't show the coefficients of covariates that don't interact with group as they don't have any effect on these coefficients, if I'm right).

However, I would like to know if there is a significant overall change in rt between groups, after having controlled for other covariates, so I would like the coefficients groupHC and groupNI to reflect the change in mean for all levels of pres and acc.

I guess a solution to this would be setting contrasts. So i can set up a sum contrast for pres, which is balanced:

```
     [,1]
diff    1
idem   -1
```

My question is: as acc is unbalanced (there are way more data-points for acc=1 than for acc=0) what is the proper way of setting contrasts for acc
so that my coefficients for groupHC and groupNI reflect the overall tendency and not just the effect for subgroups?
Would it rather be:

```
     [,1]
acc1    1
acc0   -1
```

or

```
     [,1]
acc1    'overall proportion of accurate responses'
acc0   'overall proportion of false responses'
```

I am not very happy with either solution because the first one would consider that there is the same number or accurate and false response, and the second one wouldn't consider the changes in accuracy between subjects...

Thank you very much for your answers and suggestions!

Tom

PS: Actually, I also have in my model interactions between group and continuous predictors, which make the problem of estimating the overall effect of group even trickier! I can't find a way to set sum-contrasts for continuous predictors (if that means anything), does it mean that I can only know the effect of group at a certain value of my continuous predictors?

Comment: Could you expand or at least define and explain your many abbreviations, to make this intelligible?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Actually, apart from rt (response time, continuous) the abbreviations all refer to categorical factors or levels of a factor so they are not meaningful by themselves and the question holds for any factors. 
 
"rt": response time.__ "pres": a categorical factor with two levels ("idem" and "diff", whether the probe is the same or not as the target during a match-to-sample)__ "acc" (accuracy): a categorical factor with levels 0 and 1 __ "group": categorical factor with three groups ("HC", "NC", "NI")